# Create a notification in the drawer without an icon (example included)?

Tags: android, android-notifications

As in the example below, how can I create a notification without an icon?  I can't find a way to create a notification without an icon.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What code have you tried to use so far?

Comment: I have attempted to avoid even setting "setSmallIcon()", but then the notification does not even appear.  I have also attempted setting the notification to transparent, but this method still takes up the space of a notification icon, without actually showing it.  I know Jelly Bean supports setting a notification to minimum priority (this is used for Google Now notifications) which prevents an icon from showing in the notification area, but does not prevent one from showing in the notification drawer.